# Quadratic variation of independent processes

Tags: random-variables, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

when reading some lecture notes of stochastic calculus, I have notice that often the professor seems to use the fact that:

given $B^1$ and $B^2$ as two independent Brownian motion, then we have:
$$ \langle B^1, B^2 \rangle_t = 0$$
Is this true? Can anybody explain why?

TBN: angle brackets mean "quadratic variation of the processes".

Answer (score 0):

One can show that if $X,Y$ are continuous and independent martingales, then $\langle X, Y \rangle = 0$. One definition of the quadratic variation process is that its the unique bounded variation process, such that $XY - X_0 Y_0 - \langle X,Y \rangle$ is a local martingale starting in $0$. We can easily check that $XY$ is a martingale, so $XY - X_0 Y_0$ is especially a local martingale, so $\langle X, Y \rangle = 0$ by uniqueness. To see that $XY$ is a martingale, we need to be a little bit careful with the filtration. We could consider $\mathfrak{F}^X_t = \sigma(X_s:0\leq s \leq t)$, $\mathfrak{F}^Y_t = \sigma(Y_s:0\leq s \leq t)$ and $\mathfrak{G}_t = \sigma(\mathfrak{F}^X_t, \mathfrak{F}^Y_t)$, then $XY$ is adapted to $\mathfrak{G}$ and integrable. Furthermore, for $A \in \mathfrak{F}^X_s$ and $B \in \mathfrak{F}^Y_s$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[1_{A \cap B} X_t Y_t] =\mathbb{E}[1_{A} X_t] \cdot \mathbb{E}[1_B Y_t] = \mathbb{E}[1_{A} X_s] \cdot \mathbb{E}[1_B Y_s] =  \mathbb{E}[1_{A \cap B} X_s Y_s] $$
and since these sets $A \cap B$ generate $\mathfrak{G}$, we see that $XY$ is a martingale.

Also, the other direction does not hold, i.e. $\langle X, Y \rangle = 0$ does not imlpy that $X,Y$ are independent. Consider a 2d BM. $B = (B^{(1)}, B^{(2)})$, then one can introduce an appropriate stopping time $T$, define $X = (B^{(1)})^T$, $Y = (B^{(2)})^T$, then $X,Y$ are not independent if $T$ is chosen right

Answer (score -1):

The process $B = (B^1, B^2)$ is a 2-dimensional Brownian motion, hence a standard Wiener-process (on the natural filtration), so the Levy-theorem states that the covariation matrix is diagonal (we might need that they are continuous). I believe there should be an easier way though.

Edit: Looking back into my lecture, we showed once by direct calculation that the approximation of the quadratic covariation $ \tau_n ( \langle B^1 , B^2 \rangle )_t $ tends to 0 for a Riemann decomposition, which should also yield the claim.
I think another option would be to prove that $ B^1 B^2 $ is already a martingale (wrt some natural filtration), as the quadratic covariation is the only process in $ \mathcal{V} $ (the class of continuous processes starting in 0 and with bounded variation) s.t. $ B^1 B^2 - \langle B^1 , B^2 \rangle$ is a local martingale. I'm not sure, but this might also require continuity of $B^1$ and $B^2$ .

I hope this helps